# Race conditions with JavaFX worker threads and PropertyChangeSupport

Tags: concurrency, javafx

I am working on a system that uses multiple worker threads inside of a JavaFX Task.  The Callable objects on these threads inside of the Task use PropertyChangeSupport to communicate certain state change information back to listeners (e.g. intermediate results).  I am using PropertyChangeListeners to monitor these changes and create derivative objects off of them that are accessed by other objects.  Once the Task is finished I am using JavaFX to display information, some of which is gleaned from the PropertyChange events that are emitted.

My question is: is there a potential for a race condition between the Task finishing and the PropertyChangeEvents getting processed (which I would assume would happen on the JavaFX application thread, but not completely sure).

As a concrete example, consider an image that is getting split into chunks for processing in multiple steps. At each step, an intermediate image is generated and a propertyChange event is getting fired for that intermediate image. At the end of processing, I want to be able to display the final image as well as all the images generated in the meantime in a JavaFX Scene. Will the propertyChange events all get processed before the FX thread repaints/refreshes?

I realize that the JavaFX documentation has an example with the Task api doc discussing returning intermediate results ([JavaFX Task API Documentation](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/concurrent/Task.html)).  That example uses the JavaFX Observable* objects. I would think that PropertyChangeEvents would run on the same thread similar to the FX observable object and as such there should not be a race condition between finishing a non-FX thread and getting results on the FX thread, but thought I would see if there is anything I might not be thinking of.

Thanks in advance for any discussion or thoughts.

- Chooks

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that PropertyChangeEvents will run on the same thread as the FX observable objects. This is, however, a different thread from the Task itself.

However, you don't have any guarantee that all of the propertyChange events will get processed before the FX thread repaints/refreshes. In fact, various parts of the display could get repainted multiple times between different propertyChange events, depending on how long they take and the specific timing involved. Also, other FX events could be interspersed between the propertyChange events and the repainting as well. However, you should be guaranteed that any UI elements updated by any given propertyChange event will be eventually repainted at some time after they are updated. So the display will eventually "catch up" to any changes that are made by your propertyChange handlers, and will eventually repaint any areas that were changed.